# How to enforce constrained polymorphism on a function in OCaml

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml, variant

I'm working with `yojson` library and I'm trying to write a function which given some json, retruns a list, if it's a list or an error otherwise. Crucially, I want the function to work on any Yojson's subtype (`Yojson.Basic`, `Yojson.Safe`, `Yojson.Raw` etc). I have written the following type declaration:

```
val expect_list : ([< Yojson.t ] as 'j) -> ('j list, exn) result
```

It seems straightforward to implement:

```
let expect_list = function
| `List js -> Ok js
| #Yojson.t -> Error (Failure "Not a list!")
```

Now OCaml agrees that the argument has type `[< Yojson.t ]`, but insists on the result having the monomorphic type `Yojson.t`. This is bad, because when I input `Yojson.Safe.t` I want to be able to constrain result to the same type, which I cannot figure out how to do. I can think of no reason why it shouldn't be possible…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that the type scheme `[< Yojson.t]` does not match any of the type `Yojson.Safe.t` nor `Yojson.Basis.t` type because the recursion in the `Yojson.t` type is closed.

One option is thus to avoid over-constraining the `expect_list` function:

```ml
let expect_list = function
| `List js -> Ok js
| x -> Error (Failure "Not a list!")
```

then `expect_list` will have the type

```ml
val expect_list : [> `List of 'a ] -> ('a, exn) result
```

and behaves as expected when applied to a subtype of `Yojson`:

```ml
let safe_expect_list (x: Yojson.Safe.t) = expect_list x
```

```
val safe_expect_list : Yojson.Safe.t -> (Yojson.Safe.t list, exn) result
```

Another option is to define an open-recursion variant of the Yojson.t type.
This can be done by adding a type parameter `'mu` to the definition of the type and replacing all recursive occurrence of `Yojson.t` in
the definition by this parameter `'mu`:

```ml
type 'mu rt =[ 
    `Assoc of (string * 'mu) list
  | `Bool of bool
  | `Float of float
  | `Floatlit of string
  | `Int of int
  | `Intlit of string
  | `List of 'mu list
  | `Null
  | `String of string
  | `Stringlit of string
  | `Tuple of 'mu list
  | `Variant of string * 'mu option
]
```

A first observation is that the scheme `[< _ rt ]` matches all the types `Yojson.t`, `Yojson.Safe.t` and `Yojson.Base.t`:

```ml
let test (x: Yojson.Safe.t) (y: Yojson.t) : [< _ rt ] * [< _ rt ] = x, y
```

because it doesn't add any constraints on the argument of the variant that corresponds to the "recursive hole" `'mu`.

We can thus use that type as a finer constraint in the `expect_list` function

```ml
let expect_list = function
| `List js -> Ok js
| #rt -> Error (Failure "Not a list!")
```

```
val expect_list : [< 'a rt ] -> ('a list, exn) result
```

The difference with the `#Yojson.t` pattern is that the `#rt` pattern does not impose any constraint on the type of the elements of the list under the  `` `List `` constructor contrarily to the `#Yojson.t` pattern which requires the type of the elements of the list to be exactly `Yojson.t`.

This version also has the expected behavior when applied to a variant of the yojson type:

```
let safe_expect_list (x: Yojson.Safe.t) = expect_list x;;
```

```
val safe_expect_list : Yojson.Safe.t -> (Yojson.Safe.t list, exn) result
```

One way to understand why this open-recursion type is useful in general is that the standard `Yojson.t` type can be defined as

```ml
type t = 'mu rt as 'mu
```

In other words, the open-recursion type constructor `rt` defines one layer of the recursive structure of the `Yojson.t` and the standard type can be obtained by stating that all layers are the same.

Comment: Ah, that was a tricky one. It's obvious now that I think about it. Thanks!